# Reverting back a buffer to what it was x minutes ago

Tags: undo

This question is inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/726942/. 
I am wondering if it is possible to revert back a buffer to its state of x minutes ago.

Comment: No, but you can get back the state a file was in before you started editing and saving it, if you use automatic backups.  See the Emacs manual, node [Backup](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html) and its subnodes. By default, Emacs backs up your file in the state it was in before you edited it, By default it gives the backup file the same name, with `~` appended.

Comment: While it's not implemented, it could be done. The question is: how many people would want it? Will it be worth doing it?

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't.  Emacs doesn't record timestamps when saving undo information.